# CLLocationManager Repeating Few Times

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, gmsmapview

Having a bit of an issue. I have a GMSMapView in my application and it points to the users location upon loading. When the app loads I have the locationManager set to display the latitude in the log once it finds the users position. Right now it displays the latitude over 3 times (I plan to make this post to my server). When I launch my application I will have quite a few users and the extra 3 server requests per user would be a lot for a server to handle. I am wondering is there anything I have done wrong in the code or is there a way to get around this? Will attach the code below.

Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:(id)self];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];


    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:17.0];
    [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
    latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"latitude = %g", latitude);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

didUpdateToLocation was deprecated way back in iOS6. Use the replacement didUpdateLocations, and then just pick off the last element of the array e.g.:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    location = [locations lastObject];
    // ...
    latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
```